# SED isn't removing text

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Trying to remove strings from a bunch of text files and using SED within a shell script under OSX Mavericks.

Basically, the text files contain encoded line-breaks/carriage-returns that are messing up my workflow down the line and I want to get rid of them all.

Up front I'll say that I'm an amateur programmer, so this script will probably look painful to the trained eye.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `ls *.xml`; do
  sed '/&#xD;/d' $f > "${f/.xml/}".tmp1
done
rm *.xml

for f in `ls *.tmp1`; do
  sed '/&#xA;/d' $f > "${f/.tmp1/}".tmp2
done
rm *.tmp1

for f in `ls *.tmp2`; do
  sed '/&lt;/d' $f > "${f/.tmp2/}".tmp3
done
rm *.tmp2

for f in `ls *.tmp3`; do
  sed '/&gt;/d' $f > "${f/.tmp3/}".xml
done
rm *.tmp3
```

Comment: What makes you think it is not working?

Comment: Please show some (minimal) sample input and what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to use temporary files:

```
for f in *.xml; do
    sed -e '/&#xD;/d; /&#xA;/d; /&lt;/d; /&gt;/d' "$f"
done
```

When you find the output correct, add `-i` option to sed which enables in-place editing.

```
sed -i -e ...
```

Also there's no need to use `ls *.xml`.

Awk solution:

```
for f in *.xml; do
    awk '{gsub(/&#xD;/, " "); gsub(/&#xA;/, " "); gsub(/&lt;/, " "); gsub(/&gt;/, " ")}1' "$f" > "$f".temp && cat "$f".temp > "$f" && rm "$f".temp
done
```

It's a little dangerous so please test with example files first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55466/discussion-between-twitch-and-konsolebox).

Comment: It's easy to install GNU sed on OS X by installing [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), and then `brew install gnu-sed`. Then just use `gsed` and you'll be using the same sed that all the Linux people are.